# Use depth bias for shadows in deferred shading

Tags: depth-buffer, shadow-mapping

We are building a deferred shading engine and we have a problem with shadows.

To add shadows we use two maps: the first one stores the depth of the scene captured by the player's camera and the second one stores the depth of the scene captured by the light's camera. We then ran a shader that analyzes the two maps and outputs the third one with the ready shadow areas for the current frame.

The problem we face is a classic one: Self-Shadowing:
[image: Self-Shadowing]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC340448.jpg))</sub>

A standard way to solve this is to use the slope-scale depth bias and depth offsets, however as we are doing things in a deferred way we cannot employ this algorithm. Any attempts to set depth bias when capturing light's view depth produced no or unsatisfying results.

So here is my question: MSDN article has a convoluted explanation of the slope-scale:

```
bias = (m × SlopeScaleDepthBias) + DepthBias
Where m is the maximum depth slope of the triangle being rendered, defined as:
m = max( abs(delta z / delta x), abs(delta z / delta y) )
```

Could you explain how I can implement this algorithm manually in a shader? Maybe there are better ways to fix this problem for deferred shadows?

Update: trying to implement normal-offset shadows. Current state:
[image]

Image with no bias applied:
[image]

Normal offset bias applied, it works with the teapot, but look what it does with all the other shadows:

[image]

I even tried adding the NDotL term, it does not help:

```
float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
float nDotL = dot(input.Normal,(shadowCameraPosition - worldPosition));
worldPosition.xyz += input.Normal*NormalBias*(1-nDotL);
```

Answer (score 2):

The hardware slope-scaled depth bias should work fine with deferred shading.  It only affects the depth values written into the shadow map, so you generate the same shadow map regardless of whether you're using forward or deferred shading.  Is it possible you're not reconstructing position from (camera) depth correctly when you do your lighting passes?  That would throw off the points where you're sampling the shadow map, which could cause issues like this.

In general, though, I prefer [normal-offset shadows](http://www.dissidentlogic.com/old/#Normal%20Offset%20Shadows) instead of using depth bias.  When drawing the shadow map, you use the vertex shader to offset each vertex inward a small distance along its normal.  This helps shadow acne without introducing the light leaking artifacts typical of slope-scaled depth bias.

Comment: >you use the vertex shader to offset each vertex inward a small distance along its normal < How much is "a small distance"?

Comment: @TravisG Depends on your scene - or more precisely, on the world-space size of a shadow map texel.  In practice I just tweak the distance until I don't see shadow acne anymore.

Comment: Ok I am moving the vertices when drawing shadows like this:

input.Position.xyz += input.Normal*NormalBias; - before doing anything else. The result is still unsatisfying. I read that I need to adjust the UV coords for the shadow map lookup, how can I do it?

Comment: see the picture in the question.

Comment: @cubrman Like I said, it's worth checking whether you're reconstructing position correctly and accurately.  Also, I don't understand the lighting in that picture - it looks like you've got a bunch of lighting on what should be the dark side of the teapot.

Comment: This technique mutilates the shadows on the floor, I am definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: The lighting is handcrafted :). The player will only see this side of the picture, so I cannot afford it to be dark :). So the light source is detached from the shadow source here. When the shadows are working, I will simply set them to be very subtle. But the shadows ARE computed correctly be sure, I have a camera that I use to capture them and that camera is used afterwards to compute the camera-space texture coordinates. I added more pictures, the problem is definitely not with the position reconstruction.

Comment: @cubrman It looks like you might be inflating the shadows instead of shrinking them?  Remember, you're supposed to offset *inward* along the normal.  The `NormalBias` value should be negative.

Comment: I tried it both ways but it indeed helps the self-shadowing problem only when they are negative but it distorts shadows badly, that's the problem. Does it not distort them in your case? Just look at the hunter's shadow (the one with the gun)! MJP samples shadow map depending on the normal (http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/shadow-maps/), but I cannot do that! I don't have normal data when sampling the sadowmap.

Comment: @cubrman Well, the algorithm does change the shape of the shadows but usually not by enough to make a visible difference.  If you can't get rid of the acne without distorting the shape of the shadows a lot, your shadow map resolution is probably too slow for this to work.  Does the shadow map cover the whole playing field?  If so, can you restrict it so it just covers the area visible to the camera?  That should improve resolution a lot.

Comment: I actually was drawing my shadow map into a smaller surface than the client's resolution (width/2, height/2) to improve speed, and yes the shadow map covers the entire screen. If the technique will only work with high resolution shadow map, I guess I will need to find a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem when using R32Float as shadow depth, here's my code:

```
float dx = ddx(depth);
float dy = ddy(depth);
const float bias = max(abs(dx), abs(dy)) * YOUR_SLOPE_SCALED_BIAS;
return depth + bias;
```

My recommendation is to use hardware depth instead of color buffer, and the depth bias / polygon offset will work correctly; I use R32Float just to workaround a bug of some game engine.